# Nested embedded and relations with Room

Tags: android, observable, android-room, relationships, android-livedata

I have a database structure like that:

```
Item
- id
- status_id
- title

Status
- id
- name

Feature
- id
- name

ItemFeature
- item_id
- feature_id
- value
```

I'd like to load the entire graph in a `LiveData<List<Item>>` collection... I know I have to make a POJO with `@Embedded` and `@Relation` attributes, but no matter how I design those nested POJOs, Room constantly reports that some columns are missing from the query.

My last attempt was something like that:

```
public class ItemFeatureAndRelated {
  @Embedded
  public ItemFeature itemFeature;

  @Embedded
  public Feature feature;
}

public class ItemAndRelated {
  @Embedded
  public Item item;

  @Embedded
  public Status status;

  @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "item_id")
  public List<ItemFeatureAndRelated> itemFeatures;
}
```

I need a `LiveData<List<Item>>` so I can be notified of any database change in the Item table and refresh my interface.